Saving a stable diffusion model for later use
I am new to ML and plan to use KerasCV stabledifussion model to generate images from text. The example on the KerasCV website is straightforward but I could not find a way to save the model locally for later use. I also noticed that the library connects to hugging face to download encoder and diffusion model.
Could you please point me to the right direction to do this locally? I would like all the model and its parameters to be local and I will be using it in a server.
Also, if you have experience running such a model/server on the could, I would appreciate your guidance on the best approach wrt costs. Should I upload everything and store the whole data on the cloud or load it from hugging face? Which one would make more sense for cloud applications?
Thanks,
Doug

Here is how you can save a model in Keras.
model = ...  # Get model (Sequential,Functional Model, or Model subclass)
model.save('path/to/location.keras') #The file needs to end with the .keras extension.
Loading the model back:
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location.keras') 
reference:
https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/

Please post the relevant details here.  Answers consisting only of links are liable to be deleted.
